# How to convert a list of lists into a dataframe in python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of list which looks like:

```
[['A'],
 ['America'],
 ['2017-39', '2017-40', '2017-41', '2017-42', '2017-43'],
 [10.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 1.0],
 [5.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,1.0],
 ,
 ['B'],
 ['Britan'],
 ['2017-38', '2017-39', '2017-40', '2017-41', '2017-42', '2017-43', '2017-44'],
 [41.0, 27.0, 38.0, 36.0, 33.0, 41.0, 8.0],
 [40.0, 38.0, 28.0, 27.0, 23.0, 65.0, 4.0]]
```

I want to convert this into a dataframe which should look like

```
A America     2017-39   10.0  5.0
na   na       2017-40    6.0  7.0
na   na       2017-41    6.0  8.0
na   na       2017-42    6.0  9.0
na   na       2017-43    1.0 10.0
B Britan      2017-38   41.0 40.0
na   na       2017-39   27.0 38.0
na   na       2017-40   38.0 28.0
na   na       2017-41   36.0 27.0
na   na       2017-42   33.0 23.0
na   na       2017-43   41.0 65.0
na   na       2017-44    8.0  4.0
```

How can I code to make it possible , as I am pretty new to python, I am having a hard time.

I will really appreciate your time and effort to help me in this regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `groupby` and re-create the column

```
s=pd.DataFrame(lst).T
s.columns=s.columns//5
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x.values) for _,x in s.groupby(level=0,axis=1)]).dropna(axis=0,thresh=1)
Out[146]: 
      0        1        2   3   4
0     A  America  2017-39  10   5
1  None     None  2017-40   6   7
2  None     None  2017-41   6   8
3  None     None  2017-42   6   9
4  None     None  2017-43   1   1
0     B   Britan  2017-38  41  40
1  None     None  2017-39  27  38
2  None     None  2017-40  38  28
3  None     None  2017-41  36  27
4  None     None  2017-42  33  23
5  None     None  2017-43  41  65
6  None     None  2017-44   8   4
```

Comment: This is just brilliant +1. But probably not as fast as `itertools.chain` :).

Comment: Thanks Wen , brilliant I should say. With you and other guys around I can master python soon

Comment: @AhamedMoosa, Be careful, you may be on your way to mastering `pandas`, but this is no way equivalent to `python`. Just a friendly reminder :).

Comment: @jpp I am looking to master pandas at a start , yes as you rightly said python is an ocean and I may sink if I try to surf :) But you guys are brilliant :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A'],
 ['America'],
 ['2017-39', '2017-40', '2017-41', '2017-42', '2017-43'],
 [10.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 1.0],
 [5.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,1.0],
 ['B'],
 ['Britan'],
 ['2017-38', '2017-39', '2017-40', '2017-41', '2017-42', '2017-43', '2017-44'],
 [41.0, 27.0, 38.0, 36.0, 33.0, 41.0, 8.0],
 [40.0, 38.0, 28.0, 27.0, 23.0, 65.0, 4.0]]

result = {}
for letters, countries, dates, val1, val2 in zip(*[iter(data)]*5):
    result[tuple(letters+countries)] = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'val1':val1, 'val2':val2})
result = pd.concat(result)
print(result)
```

yields

```
                date  val1  val2
A America 0  2017-39  10.0   5.0
          1  2017-40   6.0   7.0
          2  2017-41   6.0   8.0
          3  2017-42   6.0   9.0
          4  2017-43   1.0   1.0
B Britan  0  2017-38  41.0  40.0
          1  2017-39  27.0  38.0
          2  2017-40  38.0  28.0
          3  2017-41  36.0  27.0
          4  2017-42  33.0  23.0
          5  2017-43  41.0  65.0
          6  2017-44   8.0   4.0
```

---

The main idea above is to use the ["grouper idiom"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/190597)  `zip(*[iter(data)]*5)` to group the items in `data` in groups of 5. That way, you can use

```
for letters, countries, dates, val1, val2 in zip(*[iter(data)]*5):
```

to loop through 5 items of `data` at a time.

---

[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) can accept a `dict` of DataFrames as input and concatenate them into a single DataFrame with a MultiIndex composed of the keys of the `dict`.
So the `for-loop` is used to compose the `dict` of DataFrames,

```
for letters, countries, dates, val1, val2 in zip(*[iter(data)]*5):
    result[tuple(letters+countries)] = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'val1':val1, 'val2':val2})
```

and then

```
result = pd.concat(result)
```

produces the desired DataFrame.

---

Not that you could drop the last level of the MultiIndex:

```
In [91]: result.index = result.index.droplevel(level=-1)

In [92]: result
Out[92]: 
              date  val1  val2
A America  2017-39  10.0   5.0
  America  2017-40   6.0   7.0
  America  2017-41   6.0   8.0
  America  2017-42   6.0   9.0
  America  2017-43   1.0   1.0
B Britan   2017-38  41.0  40.0
  Britan   2017-39  27.0  38.0
  Britan   2017-40  38.0  28.0
  Britan   2017-41  36.0  27.0
  Britan   2017-42  33.0  23.0
  Britan   2017-43  41.0  65.0
  Britan   2017-44   8.0   4.0
```

but I wouldn't recommend this since it makes the index non-unique:

```
In [96]: result.index.is_unique
Out[96]: False
```

and this can cause future difficulties since some Pandas operations only work on DataFrames with unique indexes.

Comment: Thanks unutbu for your answer , suggestion and educating me. I really appreciate your help. the code worked perfectly for my goal

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `itertools` to perform some chaining magic.

There are 2 essential idioms we use:

1. For identifer columns, `zip` the lengths of data lists together with identifers.
2. For data columns, use `chain.from_iterable` (assigned to `chainer`) to combine every 5th sublist.

In both cases, we utilise `islice` to avoid creating lists unnecessarily as intermediate steps.

`data` is defined as per @unutbu's post.

**Solution**

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain, islice

chainer = chain.from_iterable

lens = list(map(len, islice(data, 2, None, 5)))

res = pd.DataFrame({'id1': list(chainer(list(j)+[np.nan]*(i-1) for i, j in
                                zip(lens, islice(data, 0, None, 5)))),
                    'id2': list(chainer(list(j)+[np.nan]*(i-1) for i, j in 
                                zip(lens, islice(data, 1, None, 5)))),
                    'date': list(chainer(islice(data, 2, None, 5))),
                    'num1': list(chainer(islice(data, 3, None, 5))),
                    'num2': list(chainer(islice(data, 4, None, 5)))})

res = res[['id1', 'id2', 'date', 'num1', 'num2']]
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

    id1      id2     date  num1  num2
0     A  America  2017-39  10.0   5.0
1   NaN      NaN  2017-40   6.0   7.0
2   NaN      NaN  2017-41   6.0   8.0
3   NaN      NaN  2017-42   6.0   9.0
4   NaN      NaN  2017-43   1.0   1.0
5     B   Britan  2017-38  41.0  40.0
6   NaN      NaN  2017-39  27.0  38.0
7   NaN      NaN  2017-40  38.0  28.0
8   NaN      NaN  2017-41  36.0  27.0
9   NaN      NaN  2017-42  33.0  23.0
10  NaN      NaN  2017-43  41.0  65.0
11  NaN      NaN  2017-44   8.0   4.0
```

Comment: I have checked all the solutions , this is indeed the fastest of all :) But anyways I am giving it to wen this time. Keep supporting me in my journey. I really appreciate it

Comment: @AhamedMoosa, No worries, I like Wen's solution too :).